# Ansible Dictionary Variables Definition

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am defining ansible vars defined as yaml dictionary, following format works well

```
myvars:
  var1:
    name: test1
  var2:
    name: test2
```

I want to know if following syntax is also valid for ansible?

```
myvars.var1.name: test1
myvars.var2.name: test2
```

I have seen this syntax in [elasticsearch.yml](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/settings.html#_config_file_format) file, but when I try it in my playbook vars file, ansible throws error

> "msg": "'myvars' is undefined"

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `myvars.var1.name: test1` is not valid syntax in ansible.
The variable names should not include dots.

As per documentation, https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html

> foo-port, foo port, foo.port and 12 are not valid variable names.

Comment: You are welcome! Please do mark the answer if it helped